# RabbitMQ Java Client: why does JsonRpcServer not allow most method param types?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rpc, json-rpc

I have some methods I want to expose for the client with `JsonRpcServer`:

```
    Map getById(Long o);
```

Whenever I try and use this method, a runtime exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.tools.jsonrpc.JsonRpcException: {
"code": 500,
"name": "JSONRPCError",
"message": "Internal Server Error",
"error": {
    "localizedMessage": "argument type mismatch",
    "cause": null,
    "stackTrace": [{
        "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
        "nativeMethod": true,
        "methodName": "invoke0",
        "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
        "lineNumber": -2
    }, {
        "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
        "lineNumber": 62
    }, {
        "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "className": "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
        "lineNumber": 43
    }, {
        "fileName": "Method.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
        "lineNumber": 483
    }, {
        "fileName": "JsonRpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "doCall",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.tools.jsonrpc.JsonRpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 143
    }, {
        "fileName": "JsonRpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "handleStringCall",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.tools.jsonrpc.JsonRpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 103
    }, {
        "fileName": "StringRpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "handleCall",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.StringRpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 48
    }, {
        "fileName": "RpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "handleCall",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 176
    }, {
        "fileName": "RpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "handleCall",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 163
    }, {
        "fileName": "RpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "processRequest",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 149
    }, {
        "fileName": "RpcServer.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "mainloop",
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer",
        "lineNumber": 115
    }, {
        "fileName": "RabbitConfiguration.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "lambda$jsonRpcServer$0",
        "className": "com.ofaly.comments.RabbitConfiguration",
        "lineNumber": 56
    }, {
        "fileName": null,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "run",
        "className": "com.ofaly.comments.RabbitConfiguration$$Lambda$7\/82172068",
        "lineNumber": -1
    }, {
        "fileName": "Thread.java",
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "methodName": "run",
        "className": "java.lang.Thread",
        "lineNumber": 745
    }],
    "suppressed": [],
    "message": "argument type mismatch"
}
```

}

When I change the type of the argument to String, it works... And It doesn't seem to accept any other types beside String and map. Not even Objects would work as argument.

Why doesn't JsonRpcClient accept Objects?

---

Configuration:

I am using Rabbit Mq JsonRPC client with Spring boot.
My configuration looks like so:

```
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
private String rabbitmqHost;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.queue}")
private String rabbitmqQueue;

private final IRPCService rpcService;

public RabbitConfiguration(final IRPCService rpcService) {
    this.rpcService = rpcService;
}

@Bean
public Connection rabbitmqConnection() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
    return factory.newConnection();
}

@Bean
public Channel rpcChanel() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    Connection connection = rabbitmqConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(rabbitmqQueue, false, false, false, null);
    return channel;
}

@Bean
@Lazy(false)
public JsonRpcServer jsonRpcServer() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    JsonRpcServer jsonRpcServer = new JsonRpcServer(rpcChanel(), rabbitmqQueue, IRPCService.class, rpcService);
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            jsonRpcServer.mainloop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }).start();
    return jsonRpcServer;
}
```

I use it like so:

```
@Autowired
private ProxyRpcBuilder rpcBuilder;
....
rpcBuilder.create(IRPCService.class).getById(commentId);
```

My proxy looks like so:

```
@Component
public class ProxyRpcBuilder {

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.queue}")
private String rabbitmqQueue;

private final Channel channel;
private JsonRpcClient jsonRpcClient;

public ProxyRpcBuilder(Channel channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public <T> T create(Class<T> t) {
    try {
        if (jsonRpcClient == null) {
            jsonRpcClient = new JsonRpcClient(channel, "", rabbitmqQueue, 20000);
        }
        return (T) jsonRpcClient.createProxy(t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem. According to my tests, `JsonRpcServer` allows to only expose methods whose parameters are of the following types: (1) primitive types, (2) `String`, (3) `List`, (4) `Map`. For me it also worked with `Integer` and `Double`, but not with `Long`. On the other hand, the return type of the method can be any kind of object and it works.